# Compute the integral by transforming the integral to an ordinary single integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the function below that defines the vector field:

$F(x,y) = (\frac{2}{2x + 3y},\frac{3}{2x + 3y})$

With path $(\frac{e}{5}, \frac{e}{5})$ to $(\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{1})$

With integral:
$\int_C\frac{2}{2x+3y}dx +\frac{3}{2x+3y}dy$

How would I transform this into an ordinary single integral, so that I can compute its value?

Would I first transform the path into a vector and then a parametric equation?

$(1-\frac{e}{5}, 1-\frac{e}{5})$

$(x,y) = (\frac{e}{5}, \frac{e}{5}) + t(1-\frac{e}{5}, 1-\frac{e}{5})$

$ t∈ [0,1]$

$x = \frac{e}{5} +\frac{e-5}{5}t,\ y = \frac{e}{5} +\frac{e-5}{5}t$

$dx = \frac{e-5}{5}dt, \ dy=\frac{e-5}{5}dt$

Then use that to create 2 integrals?

$\int_C\frac{2}{2x+3y}dx = \int_0^1(\frac{2}{2(\frac{e}{5} +\frac{e}{5}t-t)+3(\frac{e}{5} +\frac{e}{5}t-t)})(\frac{e-5}{5}dt)$

$\int_C\frac{3}{2x+3y}dy = \int_0^1(\frac{2}{2(\frac{e}{5} +\frac{e}{5}t-t)+3(\frac{e}{5} +\frac{e}{5}t-t)})(\frac{e-5}{5}dt)$

Then use those to find two values?

Comment: What is the initial integral?

Comment: I think what I've added in now is the required initial integral

Comment: So now just add them together.

Comment: You also need to correct the path. As you have it, you are going from $(\frac{e}{5},\frac{e}{5})$ to the point $(\frac{2e}{5}-1,\frac{2e}{5}-1)$.

Comment: ok then my path should rather be.
$(x,y) = (\frac{e}{5}, \frac{e}{5}) + t(1-\frac{e}{5}, 1-\frac{e}{5})$

Comment: yeah that looks right. Now when you add them together, notice they are both integrals w.r.t. $dt$, over the same domain ($[0,1]$).

Comment: yes, thank you. I really appreciate the help